# Sendmail Subject in Laravel 5.1

Tags: email, sendmail, swiftmailer, subject

I want send email with subject using variable , this is code

```
public function sendmail(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'subject'   =>  $request->input('subject'),
        'name'  => $request->input('name'),
        'phone' =>  $request->input('phone'),
        'email' =>  $request->input('email')
    ];
    Mail::send('mail.sendmail' , $data, function($msg){
        $msg->from('mygmail.com', 'Avil');
        $msg->to('mygmail@gmail.com', 'Avil')->subject('Welcome to Laravel 5.1');
    });
    return redirect()->route('contact.index');
}
```

I wanna subject not "Welcome to Laravel 5.1", Subject is

```
public function sendmail(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'subject'   =>  $request->input('subject'),
        'name'  => $request->input('name'),
        'phone' =>  $request->input('phone'),
        'email' =>  $request->input('email')
    ];
    Mail::send('mail.sendmail' , $data, function($msg){
        $msg->from('mygmail@gmail.com', 'Hung Nguyen');
        $msg->to('mygmail@gmail.com', 'Hung Manh')->subject($data['subject']);
    });
    return redirect()->route('contact.index');
}
```

When I running display error :

> Undefined variable: data

Please help me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass along $data to the callback in your send method. Refer the line where Mail façade is used.

```
public function sendmail(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'subject'   =>  $request->input('subject'),
        'name'  => $request->input('name'),
        'phone' =>  $request->input('phone'),
        'email' =>  $request->input('email')
    ];
    Mail::send('mail.sendmail' , function($msg) use($data){
        $msg->from('mygmail@gmail.com', 'Hung Nguyen');
        $msg->to('mygmail@gmail.com', 'Hung Manh')->subject($data['subject']);
});
    return redirect()->route('contact.index');
}
```